# Escaping CSS string with ember JS not working

Tags: ember.js

like many people (I think), I get warnings in console when binding style attributes to elements in my templates.

For example, I got an ember view containing a div which has this style attribute :

```
style="{{view.isClosing}};"
```

Now, I get the warning that this string is not escapes properly and can makes that vulnerable to XSS attacks.

I went to this link : http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_warning-when-binding-style-attributes

And then tried putting this in my view :

```
isClosing: Ember.computed('display', function () {
    if (this.get('conv.isClosing')) {
        return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString("display:");
    } else {
        return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString("display: " + this.get('display'));
    };
}),
```

The warning does not disappear, and when I try doing it with the function escapeCSS as they say in the doc, it tells me that escapeCSS is not defined. Now what is this function and how should I do it?

Thank you

Comment: I believe they expect you to implement escapeCSS yourself

Comment: @nruth - that makes sense. I couldn't find any info on that. But now I'm wondering why they say that... doesn't the SafeString take care of it?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_escaping-content-in-htmlbars), you want to use `Ember.String.htmlSafe` instead of `Ember.Handlebars.SafeString`.

```
isClosing: Ember.computed('display', function () {
    if (this.get('conv.isClosing')) {
        return new Ember.String.htmlSafe("display:");
    } else {
        return new Ember.String.htmlSafe("display: " + this.get('display'));
    };
}),
```

Comment: This still throws me the warning, there must be something I don't understand in this.

Comment: You do have a semi-colon on the outside of your Handlebars expression. What happens if you remove that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe GJK was correct. Your problem was you included the quotes.

```
<div style="{{view.isClosing}};">
```

should have been

```
<div style={{isClosing}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I did it.

Instead of using Ember.String.htmlSafe() method I simply returned a variable equals to "display:;" or "display:none;" with a htmlSafe() call at the end. Still dont know why the Ember method didn't work.

Thank you for your answers.